# How to bring a nohup task to foreground after the shell is closed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I executed the command below in a linux shell:

```sh
$ nohup run &
```

Here `run` is a blocking command. Then I close the shell and start a new one. However in the new shell I cannot bring the task to foreground via `fg`, nor can I see it via `jobs`. Is there still a way to bring it to foreground?

Comment: I don't think you can attach a background process to and arbitrary interactive shell. Read the accepted answer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) question. While it discusses your problem in the context of the utility called _screen_, which you don't use, the answer still contains plenty of pointers which seem to be relevant to you. Alternatively, you may want to use _screen_. I can't tell whether or not this is feasible for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `screen` instead of `nohup`:

```
screen -dmS demo bash -c 'while ! read -t 1;do echo $((i++));done'
```

Note: there are no `&`.

Then exit... Later, you could:

```
screen -x demo
```

Hit keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>d</kbd> to leave console running

Or

```
gnome-terminal -e 'screen -x demo'
```

Then, simply close window to leave process running.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `run` is a subprocess of the shell, and when the `shell` closes, `run` also closes.
Maybe using `tmux` or `screen` can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue a lot. If you want to kill it, what I usually do is

```
top | grep {command_name} | grep {user_name}
```

and if you wait, the background process would show up. The very first column is pid so you can

```
kill -9 {pid}
```

Beware it also greps all other commands and stats that includes string "run", so you should carefully check if it is what you really want. ( Command name is usually on the last column )

For example, assume you are using AWS AMI, which default user name is ec2-user

```
top | grep run | grep ec2-user
```

gets output like

```
371 ec2-user  20   0  110m 2668 2664 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 run-helper.sh
```

run-helper.sh is not the "run" command, so you should not kill 371